# When was war really imprisoned?

Tags: darksiders-2, darksiders

I played Darksiders 2 first and Death was trying to rescue his brother War. But in the ending of Darksiders 1, he wasn't imprisoned or anything.

Did a time skip happen after his fight with Abaddon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first Darksiders, War was tricked into imprisonment for a century. 
During that time, the events of Darksiders 2 took place. Death was then trying to rescue his brother from that imprisonment. And that skip didn't happen after Death's fight with Abaddon because Abaddon was first imprisoned by Hell and then in Darksiders 2, he was killed by Death.